# WPF DataTemplates - why the difference in rendering?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I've encountered an oddity with a very basic WPF exercise I've devised for myself, namely dynamically populating menus from a ViewModel. Given the following main window markup:

```
<Window x:Class="Demosne.Client.WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:project="clr-namespace:Demosne.Client.WPF">
<Grid>
    <Menu Height="26" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuItems}">
        <Menu.ItemTemplate>                
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <!--<MenuItem Header="File" />
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" />-->
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

and the ViewModel(s):

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private IList<MenuItemViewModel> _menuItems = new List<MenuItemViewModel>() 
    { 
        new MenuItemViewModel() { Text = "File" }, 
        new MenuItemViewModel() { Text = "Edit" } 
    };

    public IList<MenuItemViewModel> MainMenuItems
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _menuItems; 
        }
    }
}

    public class MenuItemViewModel
{      
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public IList<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _menuItems; 
        } 
    }

    private IList<MenuItemViewModel> _menuItems = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();
}
```

I would expect the GUI to *exactly* reproduce the the result of the two commented-out lines in the markup - two MenuItems called File and Edit.

However, the bound version behaves strangely on mouseover:

Markup version:

[image]

Bound version:

[image]

Why are they different?

Comment: I think this should help you. Same problem. http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/14/5149692.aspx

Comment: The situation is similar, but not quite the same. I think I'm going to have to read that article a few more times before I understand it. I thought the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` was supposed to solve that problem by implicitly creating a tree of `MenuItem`, so that the problem with child items with no visual representation doesn't happen.

Comment: Who the hell downvoted this?

Comment: I also had a similar issue, blogged about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2011/11/28/how-to-to-create-dynamic-submenus-in-wpf.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting funny results, because you are not really using the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` the correct way.

When you set a itemssource on a Menu, it will create a MenuItem for each object in the collection, and if you also supply a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with a itemssource set, it will create MenuItems for each of the child objects in that collection as well, down the hierarchy.

In your case, you've added a MenuItem yourself in the template, which is not needed. The framework creates those items implicitly for you. And this is causing the menu to behave oddly.

So to get a correct result you should do something like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**Update**
By setting a DataTemplate on something, you are telling WPF that you want to control, how each of its items should be displayed.

In this case a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is used, which is a template for generating headered controls. This kind of control contains a header and an items collection.

When you apply this kind of template to an object, whatever you have put in the template will be used as the header, and the items collection will be created by applying the template to each of the child objects in the collection set as the ItemsSource on the template. So it will recursively apply the template to all objects in the hierarchy.

In your example, you have a Menu. You could just create it by doing this:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuItems}" />
```

It would work fine, but since you have not applied a template, to tell it how the items in the collection should be displayed, it will just create a MenuItem for each object in the itemssource and call `ToString()` on it. This value will then be used as the Header property on the MenuItem.

Since that not what you want, you have to apply a template, to tell WPF what you would like to be displayed as the content in the header of the implicitly generated MenuItem.

In my example I simply made a template containing a TextBlock, which binds to the Text property on the viewmodel.

**Update 2**
If you now want to set properties on the implicitly created menuitems, you have to that by setting the `ItemContainerStyle` property on the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. The styled defined here will be applied to all the generated menuitems.

So to bind the Command property of the MenuItem to a Command property on the viewmodel you can do this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Command"
                Value="{Binding Command}" />
    </Style>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks; like @kmatyaszek's answer below this also produces the right visuals, but I'm still not sure I really understand why. The explanation of why what I've done is wrong is pretty clear, but I can't really see why the StackPanel is necessary - don't MenuItems know how to display child MenuItems already? All I want to do is i) make them present and ii) set their text. In my mind, `DataTemplate` controls data - and StackPanel isn't data, it's layout. Why is it involved?

Comment: A DataTemplate defines now you want to display the data. I've updated my answer to explain this.

Comment: Thanks. Not entirely convinced that WPF expresses what it's actually doing very clearly in this case. This complicates matters somewhat in that I was intending to bind a Command to each MenuItem - but since they're generated implicitly by the template, I no longer have access to the Command property in markup.

Comment: This is possibly by setting the ItemContainerStyle property on the HierarchicalDataTemplate. That way you can set the binding to the command in a style.

Comment: Iv'e added some code to my answer to show how to bind the command.

Comment: Thanks - this now does what I was hoping it would. The styles seem like a hack, to be honest, but they do what I'm looking for. Thanks for the effort you've put in with all the follow-ups.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
        <MenuItem.Template>
             <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}" />
             </ControlTemplate>
         </MenuItem.Template>
     </MenuItem>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

MenuItem ControlTemplate Example ([msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

> Controls in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) have a
>   ControlTemplate that contains the visual tree of that control. You can
>   change the structure and appearance of a control by modifying the
>   ControlTemplate of that control. There is no way to replace only part
>   of the visual tree of a control; to change the visual tree of a
>   control you must set the Template property of the control to its new
>   and complete ControlTemplate.

OK let's see now on the visual tree.

If we have something like this:

```
<Menu Height="26" Grid.Row="1">
     <MenuItem Header="File" />
     <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
 </Menu>
```

Visual tree of this is represented below:

[image]

Ok, so `MenuItem` has `ContentPresenter` with `TextBlock`.

What happens if we have `HierarchicalDataTemplate` ?

```
 <Menu.ItemTemplate>                
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </Menu.ItemTemplate>
```

Let's see on the visual tree:

[image]

Wow, what it is???

So if you don't specified `ControlTemplate` of `MenuItem`, it is  itself `ContentPresenter` of the `MenuItem` (you can see this on the second screen). So,  you must override `ControlTemplate` of the `MenuItem` if you want use it in `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (first screen).

Below is the visual tree with my solution:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's worth a go, but I need to ask - Why? What is this meant to do that's different?

Comment: @TomW check my answer again :)

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand a bit better now, and I'm convinced by the examples of the resulting visual tree. This seems to contradict @Peter Hansen's answer in that there is a `MenuItem` inside the HierarchicalDataTemplate. I am led to believe that this creates MenuItems for you, so won't this produce a MenuItem with a MenuItem as its Header property?